# Selecting from table and inserting in another table

Tags: php, mysql

Firstly I apologize for my bad english (its not my primary language)

This code is supposed to select to show details about the order by selecting the id of the transaction from orders page and then it will search the database from order_items table and displaying them to the user. I have no problems with this if it was information I need to display from the same table. The only difference here is that it should be displayed from another table. (I have set the foreign key to order_id).

index.php

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" href="viewform.php?view_id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">View Order Details</a>
```

viewform.php

```
if(isset($_GET['view_id']) && !empty($_GET['view_id']))
{
    $id = $_GET['view_id'];
    $stmt_edit = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT order_id, product_id, quantity FROM `order_items` WHERE id =:uid');
    $stmt_edit->execute(array(':uid'=>$id));
    $edit_row = $stmt_edit->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    extract($edit_row);
}
else
{
    header("Location: index.php");
```

When I run this code I get this error:

Warning: extract() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\shopping_cart\cms\orders\editform.php on line 13

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ID='34'' at line 4 in C:\xampp\htdocs\shopping_cart\cms\orders\editform.php:42 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\shopping_cart\cms\orders\editform.php(42): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\shopping_cart\cms\orders\editform.php on line 42

Comment: In your other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/39731535/ you're using `$db_con` and this one `$DB_con`, why was that changed? Which API are you using to connect with here? and why are you using `extract()`? and how is thing being fetched from `$row['id']`? Your question is way too unclear. What you posted for an error `near 'WHERE ID='34''` doesn't support what you posted.

Comment: ahh yes this was a mistake about $db_con it should be in small letters now I fixed it. Now it gives me this error
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_shopping_cart\cms\orders\editform.php:10 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\shopping_cart\cms\orders\editform.php on line 10

edith: I use extract because I want to display the value $edit_row. which in my case is an array.

I think the problem here is that it is not reading the id from the index page link and connecting it with the viewform page.

Answer (score 0):

found the solution.. it's a simple solution really. It should be order_id not id since it's fetching the id from the first table and validating it with the second table.

```
$stmt_edit = $db_con->prepare('SELECT order_id, product_id, quantity FROM order_items WHERE order_id =:uid');
```